# Brakeman Warning: Unsafe parameter value in `link_to` href even after sanitizing the param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, brakeman

I have the following code on my html.haml view:

```
= link_to params[:returnurl], class: "btn btn-secondary" do
    = fa_icon 'chevron-left', class: 'm-r-quarter', text: 'Cancel'
```

When I run brakeman, I get the following warning:

```
Confidence: High
Category: Cross-Site Scripting
Check: LinkToHref
Message: Unsafe parameter value in `link_to` href
```

Even after using `sanitize` as shown below, it is still giving me the same warning:

```
= link_to sanitize(params[:returnurl]), class: "btn btn-secondary" do
    = fa_icon 'chevron-left', class: 'm-r-quarter', text: 'Cancel'
```

I am very confused why am I still getting it and how would I resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There is generally not a safe with to create a link using a passed in parameter as the value for the `href` of the link.

Imagine a nefarious agent could send a link to your page where the `returnurl` param points to a site where they could phish from details of your user or the `returnurl` could use `javascript:` and then pass the user cookie data to their server and hijack the session.

You'll want to rethink the design of this so that it's not necessary to get the `returnurl` as a parameter. Ideally you can infer it from some other information. Storing the url in the users's session is an obfuscated option, but this could still be exploited.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to at least protect from `javascript:` or similar unsafe values, here's a method I added to my `ApplicationHelper` to ensure the URI scheme is `http`:

```rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def safe_url(url)
    uri = URI.parse(url)

    uri.to_s if uri.is_a?(URI::HTTP)
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    nil
  end
end
```

This won't protect against URLs with malicious content like Mark Meyer is referring to, but does add a bit of protection.